# Value too large for defined data type

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, ext4

I need to burn a ISO (3.3GB in size) using Brasero using my Ubuntu machine, however when I try to do it which the ISO is saved in my Portable USB Drive with NTFS file system, Ubuntu 64-bit says:

```
Value too large for defined data type
```

Is there a work around for this, so I can burn ISO into disk?

```
$uname -a

Linux ubuntu-desktop 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And i tried to create a large file:

```
username:~/temp$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1048576 count=51205120+0 records in
5120+0 records out
5368709120 bytes (5.4 GB) copied, 92.9742 s, 57.7 MB/s
```

Comment: Do you have sufficient space in `/`, as it needs to write some files in  temp directory. use `df -h` to find disk space.

Comment: yest there is much space available I even did a large file using 'dd' and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk Burner softwares do not support burning of **huge** images .This at least applies to Brasero and K3B.

There seems to  be a workaround.Run these commands one by one

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.iso bs=1024 count=4589800
mkudffs file.iso  #your filename here
mkdir /media/tmpdvd # if you haven't already a directory
mount -o loop -t udf file.iso /media/tmpdvd
cp big_file /media/tmpdvd
umount /media/tmpdvd
```

Then try to burn the file using GUI or terminal as per your choice.

---

If the above method dosen't work, see the output of

```
ulimit -f
```

if it is not unlimited, run this command

```
ulimit -f unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand the beforementioned workaround:

I have to also note that I've tried doing the same with a 4.8 GB ISO image on two different machines with (almost) the same version of the gnome-disk-utility package (which contains the gnome-archive-writer and gnome-archive-mounter tools) and I had the same error on the 32 bit machine, however, it worked flawlessly on the 64 bit one, so I am almost sure that it has to do with the system architecture and the limits of 32 bit integers. Check the architecture of the installed package, because since x86_64 kernels support the execution of x86 apps, it is not uncommon to have both x86 and x86_64 (amd64) binaries coexisting in your system. Just replace your package with the corresponding amd64 build and it should work fine.